# How to Change 'None' Variable to 'N/A' inside for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a `df`:

```
              Company Name Symbol      CUSIP
0           Amazon.Com Inc    NaN   23135106
7        Alphabet Inc Cl A    NaN   2079K305
8                  Invalid    NaN  42mgdst34
9        Alphabet Inc Cl C    NaN   2079K107
24             Abiomed Inc    NaN    3654100
36  Apollo Global Mgmt Inc    NaN   3768E105
```

and some code that:

1. Calls a function called `read_symbol`
2. Uses `cusip` to looks up the `symbol`
3. Writes the `symbol` to the `df`

```
    base_url = "https://quotes.fidelity.com/mmnet/SymLookup.phtml" \
               "?reqforlookup=REQUESTFORLOOKUP&productid=mmnet&isLoggedIn" \
               "=mmnet&rows=50&for=stock&by=cusip&criteria={}&submit=Search"

    def read_symbol(cusip):
        r = requests.get(base_url.format(cusip))
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        symbol = soup.select_one('[href*=SID_VALUE_ID]')
        return symbol.text if symbol is not None else None

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        cusip = row['CUSIP']
        for zeroes in range(5):
            symbol = read_symbol(zeroes * "0" + cusip)
            row['Symbol'] = symbol
            if symbol is not None:
                break

    df['Symbol'].replace('None', 'N/A', inplace=True)
    return df
```

But if there is no `symbol`, I want to write `N/A`, so that the output for `index` `8` is:

```
    Company Name Symbol      CUSIP
8        Invalid    N/A  42mgdst34
```

instead of:

```
    Company Name Symbol      CUSIP
8        Invalid   None  42mgdst34
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `None` value with the desired default string.

```
# row['Symbol'] = symbol
row['Symbol'] = 'N/A' if symbol is None else symbol
```

Answer (score 1):

How about [Replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

```
df.replace('None', 'N/A', inplace=True)
```

or

```
df['col1'].replace('None', 'N/A', inplace=True)
```

Comment: I updated my code to include that but it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: `read_symbol` returns the singleton value `None`, not the string `'None'`.

Comment: @chepner - changing it to `None` rather than string `None` results in `TypeError: 'regex' must be a string or a compiled regular expression or a list or dict of strings or regular expressions, you passed a 'bool'`

Comment: Well, right.  You can't use a string replacement function on `None`.

Comment: You are right, you cannot use Replace None (NoneType).  MSD, use np.nan instead of NoneType for your dataframe.  From there you can use Replace.